# Unable to populate all drop down boxes, only first is populated from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

This is my code only first drop down box is populating. I can repeat the drop down boxes but unable to populate all drop down boxes. Please help me...

```
$sel='select Driver_name from driver_master';
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sel);
$sel1='select d_status from status';
$query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1);

echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo "<th>From</th>";
echo "<th>To</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Driver_name']."</td>";?>
    <td><select>
<?php while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){  
    $st=$row1['d_status'];
    echo "<option value='$st'>$st</option>";
    }?>
    </select></td>
<?php
    echo "</tr>";      
}
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
echo "</form>";
```

I can repeat the drop down boxes but unable to populate all drop down boxes. Please help me...

I want to show data from my database to all drop down boxes and save the selected value. the submit button that I have used is not working please tell me why?

Comment: How many `records` do you have in `driver_master` table..?

Comment: Is there any kind of error printed for you after trying submit the form?

Comment: @noddy thanks for making it more readable.

Comment: it is showing four boxes but populate only first.

Comment: is error_reporting on?

Comment: yes error_reporting is on.

Comment: No error!?...hmmm.  Are you facing blank pages? because blank pages menas syntax errors. As @noddy said, turn error_reporting on or check your php_error_log and tell us, pelase

Comment: it is showing 4 fields from driver_master & showing 4 drop down boxes from status. first have options but next 3 are empty.

Comment: can you give your site url?

Comment: sorry, it is on localhost.

Comment: there must be some error

Comment: browser does not show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some major changes to your code. In the code below I renamed some variables to some more readable names so you don't get as tangled.

I saved the results of the query which retrieves the statuses to one variable which you can easily re-use in a foreach loop. I also edited out the html parts and made it completely PHP saving you some opening and closing tags with PHP.

If you doubt the values you get back from the queries aren't quite what you expect them to be try them out in PHPmyadmin first so you know it's not the PHP syntax or formatting messing them up.

I also gave the select element a name so you can link the passed value in PHP. You can use `print_r($_POST);` In driver_status.php to check which values come through.

```
<?php
$query_driver = 'select Driver_name from driver_master';
$result_driver = mysqli_query($conn, $query_driver);
$query_statuses ='select d_status from status';
$result_statuses = mysqli_query($conn, $query_statuses);
while($row_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_statuses)){
    $statuses[] = $row_status['d_status'];
}

// $statuses now contains all statuses from the query this saves extra unnecessary queries.

echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th>From</th>";
    echo "<th>To</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row_driver = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_driver)){   
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row_driver['Driver_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td><select name='drivers[". $row_driver['Driver_name'] ."][status]'>";
        foreach($statuses as $status){
            echo "<option value='". $status . "'>". $status . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";      
}
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)  in line   echo "<td><select name='drivers[$row_driver['Driver_name'][status]]'>";

Comment: @VirenderKumar Have you made any progress with your problem?

Comment: Yes, that problem is solved. But i have another problem plz click on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936035/unable-to-store-date-to-database-in-php/28936344?noredirect=1#comment46132667_28936344

Comment: Tom Kriek , can u help me?

Comment: I'm more concerned about this question right now. Did my answer help you or not. It's not preferred to just leave this question open. I will try to help after this one is done. Don't try to flood SO with small questions and then don't bother to select an answer.

Comment: how to close the question?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$sel='select Driver_name from driver_master';
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sel);
$sel1='select d_status from status';
$query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1);

echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo "<th>From</th>";
echo "<th>To</th>";
echo "</tr>";
do {    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Driver_name']."</td>";?>
    <td><select>
<?php do{  
    $st=$row1['d_status'];
    echo "<option value='$st'>$st</option>";
    }while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)); ?>
    </select></td>
<?php
    echo "</tr>";      
}while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query));
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: can you please try `static for loop` instead of outer `do while` loop..just for debugging..

Comment: @RohitJindal Give an explanation as to why it should work. *Try this* is not enough.